# JBoss Weld throws strange exception: getTargetClass (duplicate method)

Tags: cdi, glassfish-3, jboss-weld, weld, jrebel

We have a regular CDI bean where we declare a method like:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
@LoggedIn
public class ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager extends BaseStatusShownDataManager<CcDocumentation>
{
    ...

    @Override
    protected Class<?> getTargetClass()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

There are no compile errors on the project.

After deploying to GlassFish 3.2.x, a login and redirect to the main page (the dashboard) results in the following exception (ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager is just one of many apps reachable from that page):

```
11:48:15,526 INFO    [] (165) 2016-04-26 11:48:15 JRebel: Reloading class 'de.bnext.compliance.compliancerulemgmt.view.ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager'.
11:48:15,672 INFO    [] (165) 2016-04-26 11:48:15,663 [http-thread-pool-8181(4)] ERROR de.bnext.dashboard.view.DashboardManager     - [DashboardManager.newMainManagerFilterHandlerItems()] Could not create main manager filter handler items for user=[kawu]: 
com.google.common.collect.ComputationException: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: duplicate method: getTargetClass in de.bnext.compliance.compliancerulemgmt.view.ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:397)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.getClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:632)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:703)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:686)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:695)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.weld.services.InjectionServicesImpl.aroundInject(InjectionServicesImpl.java:134)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:157)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:131)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:153)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:293)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.context.ViewScopedContext.get(ViewScopedContext.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at de.bnext.compliance.compliancerulemgmt.view.ComplianceRuleManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.setPermissionKey(ComplianceRuleManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at de.bnext.dashboard.view.DashboardManager.createFilterHandlerDashboardItem(DashboardManager.java:347)
    at de.bnext.dashboard.view.DashboardManager.createFilterHandlerDashboardItem(DashboardManager.java:318)
    at de.bnext.dashboard.view.DashboardManager.newMainManagerFilterHandlerItems(DashboardManager.java:797)
    at de.bnext.dashboard.view.DashboardManager.getMainManagerFilterHandlerItems(DashboardManager.java:783)
    at de.bnext.dashboard.view.DashboardManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getMainManagerFilterHandlerItems(DashboardManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:138)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:224)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jstl.core.ForEachHandler.apply(ForEachHandler.java:162)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:178)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:112)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:184)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:164)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:98)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:308)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:346)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:774)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.view.SeamViewDeclarationLanguage.buildView(SeamViewDeclarationLanguage.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at de.bnext.core.web.filter.security.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at de.bnext.core.web.filter.httpheader.HttpHeaderFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at de.bnext.core.web.filter.encoding.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.__invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.__invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: duplicate method: getTargetClass in de.bnext.compliance.compliancerulemgmt.view.ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:282)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.create(ProxyFactory.java:236)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.createClientProxy(ClientProxyProvider.java:87)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider.access$000(ClientProxyProvider.java:43)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:53)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ClientProxyProvider$1.apply(ClientProxyProvider.java:46)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.WeldException: duplicate method: getTargetClass in de.bnext.compliance.compliancerulemgmt.view.ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.addSpecialMethods(ProxyFactory.java:712)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.addMethods(ProxyFactory.java:443)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.createProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:371)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.getProxyClass(ProxyFactory.java:275)
    ... 140 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.DuplicateMemberException: duplicate method: getTargetClass in de.bnext.compliance.compliancerulemgmt.view.ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.testExistingMethod(ClassFile.java:664)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.addMethod(ClassFile.java:640)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyFactory.addSpecialMethods(ProxyFactory.java:706)
    ... 143 more
```

I can see that JRebel tries to reload the class `ComplianceRuleDocumentationManager`, but I don't know why it attempts to do so, because I was cleaning GlassFish deployment directory and some other stuff before restarting the server completely (we have a rather stable cleanup script).

Any ideas what could cause this? Why is the `getTargetClass()` method affected/causing this?

Thanks

Comment: The only thing I can guess is that weld's proxies include this exact method in their call stack.

Comment: John is right, I had the same problem and when I renamed my method to `getTargetType()`, the problem disappeared.

Comment: I've also encountered strange problems declaring `public Class<T> getGenericClass()`. In any case, making methods public that return `Class` objects should be avoided. Making it a `protected` implementation detail for subclasses seems to work however.